# mysql.user table corrupt even after re-install

Tags: mysql, centos, users

I recently corrupted the `mysql.user` table in my mysql install on centos 5.6, so I removed the `mysql` and `mysql-server` packages and then removed `/var/lib/mysql`. Then, I re-installed `mysql` and `mysql-server` via `yum`. Here is the output of `SELECT user.User FROM mysql.user;`

```
mysql> SELECT User FROM user;
+------+
| User |
+------+
| root |
|      |
| root |
|      |
| root |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anybody know if there is a data file other than `/var/lib/mysql` laying around somewhere? Or just how to solve this?

Here is the result of `SELECT Host, User FROM user;`

```
mysql> SELECT Host, User FROM user;
+---------------+------+
| Host          | User |
+---------------+------+
| 127.0.0.1     | root |
| server-name   |
| server-name   | root |
| localhost     |      |
| localhost     | root |
+---------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: How did you corrupt the mysql.user table?

Comment: I added and deleted rows from `mysql.user` and `mysql.db`

Comment: I had thought I corrupted the users table. It turns out I did not understand how the users table works. I don't agree with the negative vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it is corrupt? Try the following query: `select Host,User from user;` and you will see non-empty host columns on every row. BTW your query gives me 6 rows on a fresh Percona Server install.

Comment: I thought that there should only be one `root` user listed. I am brand-spanking new to user management in mysql, so I was definitely making an assumption. I added the output of `select Host, User from user` to my answer.

Comment: No, many `root` users are perfectly valid, they are for different hosts, see different hostnames in your query. Of course, all these hostnames are just your server names, this is normal. MySQL uses `'user'@'host'` pairs to distinguish users.